# change typed chars with android softkeyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How i can replace some characters when user type a sentence in EditText? For example when user types" Hello" changes into "Hella" immediately! I want to change some chars when user types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a text watcher. etMessage is an EditText, see this code :

```
    etMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String myString = s.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myString,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (myString.length() > 0)
                if (myString.charAt(myString.length() - 1) == 'o') {
                    etMessage.setText("Hello");
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this question but i'll try to answer to my best understanding...
use a TextChangedListener for the EditText field.
eg:

```
mySlangMaker.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(mySlangMaker));

private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private EditText mEditText;

public CustomTextWatcher(EditText mySlangMaker) {
    mEditText = mySlangMaker;
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
```

}

something like this...add the logic you want in the appropriate methods.. :)

Hope this is what you're looking for.. :)

Comment: my question is: how i can change some characters when typing, like a text auto corrector. i cant understand you'r answer